# How to make my if statement work with input

Tags: python-3.x

```py
x = input("Test: ")
if x == "test: " + 1:
    print("test")
```

I'm simply trying to make this input system with an if statement work, and Google and VS are hating me and I cannot do it.

Comment: Cannot do what, exactly? I don't really see anything wrong on the face of this code; what exactly are you typing at the prompt that it's not hitting your conditional as you expect? [ask]

Comment: That code should be throwing an error.  Can you edit the error into the question?

Answer (score 0):

your first line will set the variable `x` to have the value of whatever is entered at the prompt. It will not have the value `x = 'Test: ' + blahblah`.

It will also bring in whatever is entered as a string, so if you enter `1` it will be converted to `'1'`.

Try just doing `if x == '1':`

Answer (score 0):

An input statement returns the input given so `x == "test: " + 1:` is incorrect and also you did not capitalize your 't'. Your code will look like this when wanting to get the input as 1:

```py
x = int(input("Test: "))
if (x == '1'):
    print("test")
```

By default the input returns a string so if you type 1 which is a int it will make it into a string. You can use the `int()` function to turn the string into an int(works only if it is a number/integer, if not it throws error). Here is the code for that:

```py
x = int(input("Test: "))
if (x == 1):
    print("test")
```